# Interpolation via triangulation between a set of points on two parallel lines

Tags: algorithms, interpolation, computational-geometry, triangulation

I'm trying to develop a fast algorithm to perform 2D interpolation between two parallel lines. Along the way, I found an interesting problem and have been wrestling with it for longer than I should.

## Definitions

Let's call the two parallel lines Line A and Line B. For simplicity, let them each be parallel to the $x$-axis with $y$-values of $y_A$ and $y_B$, where $y_A<y_B$.

Line A has $N_A>1$ points sorted in order of ascending $x_{A,i}$: 
$$(x_{A,1},y_A), \; (x_{A,2},y_A), \; (x_{A,3},y_A), \; \dots, \; (x_{A,N_A},y_A)$$

In similar fashion, Line B has $N_B>1$ points sorted in order of ascending $x_{B,i}$: 
$$(x_{B,1},y_B), \; (x_{B,2},y_B), \; (x_{B,3},y_B), \; \dots, \; (x_{B,N_B},y_B)$$

In general, the lines have some overlap along the $x$-axis.

Let there be an unknown (but smooth) function $f(x,y)$ which is sampled at these points. We can denote these known function values along Line A at point $(x_{A,i},y_A)$ as $f_{A,i} \equiv f(x_{A,i},y_A)$, and along Line B at point $(x_{B,i},y_B)$ as $f_{B,i} \equiv f(x_{B,i},y_B)$.

## Problem Statement

Given these points, I know I could in principle calculate a Delaunay triangulation in order to calculate the interpolated value $f_Q$ at a query point $(x_Q,y_Q)$ in between the lines, where $f_Q$ is an estimation of the unknown function $f(x,y)$ at the query point: $f_Q \approx f(x_Q,y_Q)$.

Creating a whole triangulation for the entire set of points seems like overkill for a single point, however. I suspect there's a more efficient way to do this, e.g. by figuring out which x-coordinates are above/below $x_Q$ and/or how far away nearby points are.

**How can I figure out which triangle (out of the entire Delaunay triangulation) the query point is in without actually computing the *entire* Delaunay triangulation for all points on both lines?**

#### My work thus far:

Given a query point, I can figure out a set of three points from both lines that contains the point, but the triangle is not unique for all points inside it. In other words, if I were to choose another point in that triangle, the same algorithm I currently use might give me a different triangle to interpolate on. For a mesh of query points, this makes the mesh of interpolated values discontinuous. I'm thinking of the Delaunay triangulation because it is unique, but don't want to compute the entire scheme for every query point.

(NOTE: I'd be interested in comments about an alternate way to do interpolation between these two lines, but the answer should be focused on how to "shortcut" the Delaunay triangulation algorithm for two parallel lines.)

Comment: Assuming you are already familiar with Voronoi diagrams and their dual relationship to Delaunay triangulations, you can figure out to which Voronoi cell your query point belong, compute the vertices of that cell and test to which dual Delaunay triangle the query point belongs.

Comment: @N.Bach: How would I figure out which Voronoi cell my query point belonged in?

Comment: You find the closest point to your query point. Then by definition, your query point belongs to the Voronoi cell of that (closest) point.

Comment: @N.Bach: Of course!—computing which Voronoi cell it's in is easy. (Thanks.) But what about testing which dual Delaunay triangle the query point belongs? I've been looking at dual diagrams over the weekend and it hasn't hit me how that would be done easily. Figuring out which Voronoi cell it's in is trivially easy, as you pointed out, and that gives one vertex of the Delaunay triangle. But then there's ~3+ Delaunay triangles associated with that cell, with 4+ other vertices involved. Is there a way to do this without several guesses involving calls to a `triangle_contains_point()` routine?

Comment: This is kinda why I wasn't motivated to do a full answer. To start off, yes it is possible to perform a somewhat direct computation. Would it be significantly faster than testing a couple of nearby triangles? Honestly I'm not sure. To top it off, your problem is highly structured here with every points on two parallel lines, so I was hoping someone else would come up with something more clear-cut than my suggestion. Long-winded intro aside, I'll assume you've understood how to locally compute a voronoi cell, and know which Delaunay triangle are associated with it. Let $p$ be the closest ...

Comment: ... point to query point $q$. All triangles admit $p$ as vertex. One possibility is to switch to polar coordinate, using $p$ as origin. You don't need full polar coordinate, just the angle suffice. So basically from $p$, you know in which direction $q$ is, as well as all other vertices of the related triangles. The angle for $q$ should fall between the angles for the other two vertices that define the Delaunay triangle $q$ belongs to. Hopefully this is clear enough. Otherwise I'll have to post an illustration.